# How can I get something like ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE for another type of view?

Tags: android, view

I have a vertical menu with several `ToggleButton`. The menu has a fixed width, and I want the buttons to be equally spaced in it.

I use the `android:layout_gravity` to create some button containers, and I would like the buttons to scale inside the containers as `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE` does, i.e. to make the largest button's dimension fit in the container, maintaining the button's aspect ratio.

I tried with the button's dimensions set to `wrap_content` and the container's gravity set to `center`, but this only works when the button is smaller than the container. If it's larger, the button fits the container dimension and the button's aspect ratio is not maintained.

How can I mimic `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE` for my `ToggleButton`?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_01_bg"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_02_bg"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- more ToggleButtons -->

</LinearLayout>
```